# Check angular route path from interceptor

Tags: angular, angular-activatedroute

I have a route path configured as:

```
{
    path: 'user/:id/edit/:type',
    component: UserEditTypeComponent,
},
```

I want to reach the path from the interceptor which i could access from activated routes as:

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.activatedRoute.routeConfig.path);
}
```

This results in returning this path `user/:id/edit/:type` in the console.

I want to get the same path from interceptor which i have tried as:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let ar = this.injector.get(ActivatedRoute);
    console.log(ar.routeConfig.path);
}
```

this returns error as: `Cannot read property 'path' of null`. I have removed the path and tested and found `routeConfig` to be null.

**How do we get the activated route inside the interceptor?**

Is there any other method to access the `path` in interceptor?

If the question seems to be unclear could updated it with more information.

Comment: What is wrong with your first example using the ActivatedRoute ?

Comment: @Orodan There is nothing wrong in that example. The example is inside the component and i have a condition where i need to check the component's `path` in interceptor which is not working as expected.

Comment: you can even take a constructor in interceptor

Comment: Have you tried getting the `ActivatedRoute` via constructor injection in the interceptor? Just like you are in the component.

Comment: [check this link](https://scotch.io/@kashyapmukkamala/using-http-interceptor-with-angular2)

Comment: It's weird that you care for the current client-side route when performing an API request. Requests are usually wrapped in services which can be injected into different components, regardless of the current route.

Comment: @R.Richards  and Sravan: yup tried and same is the result.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is a little late.. but following will resolve your problem, had similar concerns..

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    console.log(activatedRoute.snapshot['_routerState'].url);
}
```

`activatedRoute.snapshot['_routerState'].url` will contain your `/user/:id/edit/:type`.

Answer (score 6):

I got it to work like this after peeking in the implementation

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
   console.log(this.router.routerState.snapshot.url);
}
```

This will give you the whole url with params and everything.
Like: `user/234?hasName=true&hasShoes=false`

Answer (score 4):

If in the interceptor the activated route and the snapshot aren't loaded with the current path or url, as a last choice, you could use the classic `window.location`

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to do it through the router object:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
    console.log(this.router.routerState.snapshot);
}
```

This way you don't have to access hidden properties.